# How to read/write/update the Calendar (IOS) and Google Calendar (Android)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-calendar-api

**With the user's permission.**

I'm looking for a way to manipulate the user device's calendar in a web application (React/JS/AWS). 
Something like the "Google Calendar API" but also working for the IOS "Calendar". 
What is the best way to read/write/update it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot access a device calendar via a web app, your web app would be running on a browser (Chrome, Mozilla, Opera, etc.) which does not have access to device calendar.

To achieve what you want, you would need to build a native app, assuming you already know react, [React Native](https://reactnative.dev/) would be a good place to start, and you can use [this](https://github.com/wmcmahan/react-native-calendar-events) library to achieve what you want